# Can't fire click event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fire click event with jquery but it doesnot work don't know why :

```
<input type="Button" name="SubmitMe" class="submit" value="Next Step >>" style="min-width:250px;" onclick="GSMValidatePostAdForm1(this.form)">

$("input[name = 'SubmitMe']").click();

Uncaught ReferenceError: GSMValidatePostAdForm1 is not defined
```

Comment: Rather obvious error message. GSMValidatePostAdForm1 is not defined - also not in your example

Comment: Are you asking why you can't call a function which doesn't exist?  I'm not sure how to even formulate an answer to that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove onclick from the attributes of input tag as you haven't written the GSMValidatePostAdForm1() function. 
Your code should look like this after changes :

```
<input type="Button" name="SubmitMe" class="submit" value="Next Step >>" style="min-width:250px;">
```